# OSGi Configuration Properties - is there any web interface for viewing the properties

Tags: jbossfuse, fuseesb, apache-servicemix

configuration properties can be listed in Fuse using config:list command in fuse.Is there any feature we can add that will provide a web interface to monitor/configure properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use hawtio, which is a web console, that has an OSGi plugin you can use to view information about OSGi, and among others it has a config admin view/editor.

If you use Fuse 6.1 or the upcoming 6.2, then hawtio comes out of the box in Fuse.

But hawtio can also be installed in fuse / karaf

- http://hawt.io/